# How to setup Topshelf with WhenCustomCommandReceived?

Tags: c#, topshelf

I'm using Topshelf to create a windows service (ServiceClass)  and i'm thinking of sending custom commands using WhenCustomCommandReceived.

```
HostFactory.Run(x =>
{
    x.EnablePauseAndContinue();
    x.Service<ServiceClass>(s =>
    {
        s.ConstructUsing(name => new ServiceClass(path));
        s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
        s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
        s.WhenPaused(tc => tc.Pause());
        s.WhenContinued(tc => tc.Resume());
        s.WhenCustomCommandReceived(tc => tc.ExecuteCustomCommand());
    });
    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
    x.SetDescription("Service Name");
    x.SetDisplayName("Service Name");
    x.SetServiceName("ServiceName");
    x.StartAutomatically();
});
```

However, i'm getting an error on the WhenCustomCommandReceived line:

Delegate 'Action< ServiceClass, HostControl, int>' does not take 1 arguments

The signature is

```
ServiceConfigurator<ServiceClass>.WhenCustomCommandReceived(Action<ServiceClass, HostControl, int> customCommandReceived)
```

I already have methods for start, stop, pause in my ServiceClass: public void Start(), etc.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to setup the Action?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, as you can see in the signature of the method, the `Action` takes three parameters, not just one. This means that you need to set it up like this:

```
s.WhenCustomCommandReceived((tc,hc,command) => tc.ExecuteCustomCommand());
```

The interesting parameter in this case would be `command` which is of type `int`. This is the command number that is sent to the service.

You might want to change the signature of the `ExecuteCustomCommand` method to accept such command like this:

```
s.WhenCustomCommandReceived((tc,hc,command) => tc.ExecuteCustomCommand(command));
```

And in the `ServiceClass`:

```
public void ExecuteCustomCommand(int command)
{
    //Handle command
}
```

This allows you to act differently based on the command that you receive.

To test sending a command to the service (from another C# project) you can use the following code:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceName"); //ServiceName is the name of the windows service
sc.ExecuteCommand(255); //Send command number 255
```

According to [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.executecommand(v=vs.110).aspx), the command value must be between 128 and 256.

Be sure to reference the System.ServiceProcess assembly in your test project.

Comment: Thanks Yacoub!  Solved my problem.  Learned something new today.

Comment: is it possible with topshelf to send command from cmd.exe? like > myservice.exe 128?